# AJAX URL issue…very odd

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page from which I am trying to make an AJAX call, but it isn't working, and I'm stumped as to why. My call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<relative URL>/index.php?action=x",
    dataType: "JSON"
}).success(function(person) {
    alert(person.name) //alerts naem
});
    return false;
});
```

and the PHP is:

```
<? 

if($_GET["action"] == "x"){

    $person = array("name"=>"Jon Doe","Reputation"=>"Good");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($person);
}

?>
```

I don't THINK the issue is a faulty URL, since it is a c/p of working calls. It seems to me (but I'm not sure) that it chooses to reuse the old 'action-values' from when the source page was loaded originally. For some reason it completely ignores my action-value…?

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use your browser's console do you see the network call being sent ? If so you can look at what the response is. that would tell you if it is actually returning something. If it is then perhaps you can replace .success with .done as the previous commenter mentioned (though this would depend on your version of jquery).   Secondly, you cannot pass json directly between php and jquery.  I believe you first have to pass the return value through $.parseJSON(person), then you can access the property as person.name

Comment: .success is correct, i use it all the time

Comment: You wont need to use $.parseJSON as he has already setting the datatype to JSON and he is returning JSON from the server

Comment: There's a suggestive edit happening `alert(person.name);` which hasn't been approved (yet). OP missed a semi-colon? `alert(person.name) //alerts naem` could it be the cause?

Comment: JavaScript is forgiving when it comes to semi colons. But yeh your right I subconsciously added that! I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the PHP into its own file rather than the index.php, which I assume is your main PHP file.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ajax.php?action=x",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (person) {
       console.log(person.name);
    }
});
```

This should be a separate file. Call it ajax.php for an example.

```
<? 
// ajax.php
if($_GET["action"] == "x"){

    $person = array("name"=>"Jon Doe","Reputation"=>"Good");
    die(json_encode($person));
}

?>
```

Just make sure ajax.php is in the route of your project and this should work. Check the console.log if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the variable into 'data':

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<relative URL>/index.php", 
    data: "action=x",
    success: function (person) {
       console.log(person.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling `index.php` with a get parameter, you *might* be echoing the json_encode **and then continuing to output everything else after the if statement**.

Try this?

```
<? 

if($_GET["action"] == "x"){

    $person = array("name"=>"Jon Doe","Reputation"=>"Good");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($person);
    exit;

}

?>
```

I'm assuming you have more content in the `index.php` below that if statement. If so, the `exit;` statement would be needed so that you only echo the json and not anything after the if statement.

The ajax response can be viewed in Google Chrome's Dev Tools, under the Network tab.

---

Let's say you had no `exit;` statement:

```
<? 

if($_GET["action"] == "x"){

    $person = array("name"=>"Jon Doe","Reputation"=>"Good");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($person);

}

?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
...etc, etc
```

The ajax response under Dev tools would look something like this:

`{"name":"Jon Doe","Reputation":"Good"}<html><head></head><body>... and so on`

which would then try to be parsed by the $.ajax into a JSON object.

But this is not possible because `<html><head></head><body>...` is not valid JSON.

Hope this helps!